# MySQL "LIKE" search doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search

I've imported a .txt database in MySQL through "LOAD DATA INFILE", and everything seemed working, the only problem is that if I search a record on the DB with the following  query:

```
 "SELECT * FROM hobby WHERE name LIKE  'Beading'"
```

it returns 0 rows, while if I use

```
""SELECT * FROM hobby WHERE name LIKE  '%Beading%'"
```

it returns 1 row, even if exist one record with name=Beading. Does anybody know what could it depend on?

Answer (score 3):

When using SQL `LIKE`:

You should use a wildcard identifier such as (or not):

1. `'%word'` - return results that the value ends with the letters: "word".
2. `'word%'` - return results that begin with the letters: "word".
3. `%word%` - return results that include the letters: "word" anywhere.
4. there are some more pattern search combination like:

   'abc' LIKE 'abc'    true

   'abc' LIKE 'a%'     true

   'abc' LIKE '*b*'    true

   'abc' LIKE 'c'      false

If you want an exact match you should use:

```
"SELECT * FROM hobby WHERE name='Beading'"
```

But `LIKE 'Beading'` should also work, so it's probably a spaces issue or case sensitivity problem.

You need to take care of collation case (sensitivity) when you want to make sure your results are complete.

Say your table is UTF...CS and you want to make an insensitive case search you should declare it in your SQL query, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM hobby WHERE name COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE 'beading'
```

try testing different approaches and see what fits your goal best.

Answer (score 1):

the first one doesnt work because Like statment you should use `'%search word%'`

you should use this one

```
      "SELECT * FROM hobby WHERE name LIKE  '% Beading %' or name LIKE '% Beading'
       or name LIKE 'Beading %' or name LIKE 'Beading'"
```

Comment: I know but I need to know if the word searched there is just on DB while with %word% I just know that there are similar words.. @echo_Me

Comment: i dont understand what you mean , but this will return all names having this Beading

Comment: Yes, I know it will return all names having Beading, but I need just the single word Beading

Comment: you maybe need to do spaces around Beading try this updated answer